# Getting rid of categorical features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, many-categories

I am working on training a reinforcement learning agent with a huge dataset of past human players' experience. Each user had to independently increase their game score. I am using the dataset because I have plenty of data and because on-policy training can be slow due to the game speed.

The only problem I have is the human player ID as a categorical feature. I have around 1000 experience play from each user and an ID should be assigned so the LSTMs can detect the sequential behavior of the game play.

Should I:

1- Serve each player's experience as an episode to the agent so to get rid of user IDs as a category

2- or keep the training batches together including all the user IDs and train the agenet with them?

The problem here is that it is complicated for me to use one-hot encode for this large category.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not explicitly modelling the player's behavior, then using IDs doesn't make any sense. The point of using categorical features is to use them in prediction - the player IDs aren't part of environment, right?

Comment: The player IDs were proposed so the agent during the pre-training understands which user started which game i.e. the training batch contains several users with their current state/action at a certain date. Now, if we serve the training batches player by player then there's no need for their IDs.

Comment: How are you going to use these IDs for unseen data?

Comment: The data is the state/action for each player in the past. Assigning to them their IDs in this case, would let the LSTM get the temporal dependency for each player. Am i missing something?

Comment: What I mean is why do you even use this data? It seems to me that RL agent is supposed to react to environment, and I don't think what player ID has to do with that

Comment: Yes exactly. But my environment is very slow for the agent to learn from it. That is why i decided to pre-train it by demonstration. Is there an alternative for the training in case of slow environment? Should I create my own gym maybe in an accelerated way?

Comment: I don't know - but I don't see the advantage of including IDs, since that's not available when your agent runs on its own.

Comment: ok i understand now. My agent will train itself with the past state/actions of other users. right?

Comment: But what about the past rewards? each player has its own final score.